# can airflow dag run sequential without dependency

Tags: airflow

i would like to create a workflow that starts after past execution have finished but not depends on their success status. meaning dags would be scheduled sequentially, without any dependency on past statuses.

i.e.:
executions by order:

2017-03-09 15:00:00 success

2017-03-09 16:00:00 failed

2017-03-09 17:00:00 success

2017-03-09 18:00:00 success

how can i do it using Airflow?
(i want it to be the same for backfill)

Answer (score 4):

- To run tasks irrespective of failed previous tasks in a given DAG:

setting the **trigger_rule** for each Operator to **dummy** or **all_done**

- To run DAGs irrespective of previous DAG Run failures:
  setting **depends_on_past=False** for each DAG

Explore more options in the trigger_rule section in the Concepts page of Airflow documentation

http://airflow.incubator.apache.org/concepts.html

Comment: does this mean that the previous run must execute the next?

Comment: what are the disadvantages of that method?

Comment: there is no disadvantage per se unless logic in your DAG/tasks demands previous tasks/dag runs to be a success